# Windows desktop has decent connection speed outgoing but times out locally

Tags: networking, windows-7, timeout

I have a desktop computer that is hooked up to our network here that is confusing me. The computer can get through the internet, transfer files over FTP, and do basic day to day tasks with reliable speed. However, when I try to ping local computers or try to remote in to a local server I time out or lose connection after a minute in. Is there something that I'm missing in my configuration of this desktop computer? I have setup other office computers, but this is the only one giving me issues. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1
Network: 35Mb TW Telcom line

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is ICMP ping Reply allowed in the firewall on the other computers? Are they running windows 7 as well? Since Windows XP SP2 ICMP Reply has been turned off. If you go into the Firewall settings ---> Advanced ---> ICMP and click the allow check box.

Also you will have to allow this thought the firewall. (Make it an exception on the Windows 7 Firewall)

What remote technology are you using? RDP? Can you RDP from the server to the client? Is this the same for all hosts.